# php: how to change array value (text)

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to change value in my array but can't for some reason...

`

My code:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" class="form-control">
    <label for="soortMeel">Soort meel:</label>
    <input type="text" name="soortMeel" id="soortMeel">

    <label for="vorm">Soort vorm:</label>
    <input type="text" name="vorm" id="vorm">

    <label for="gewicht">gewicht:</label>
    <input type="number" name="gewicht" id="gewicht">

    <label for="gewicht">row aanpassen:</label>
    <input type="number" name="arr_input" id="arr_input">

    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="add" value="add">
        <input type="submit" name="update" value="update"> 
    </div>
</form>



<?php

class brood {

    public $soort_meel;
    public $vorm_brood;
    public $gewicht;

    function __construct($soort_meel, $vorm_brood, $gewicht) {
        $this->soort_meel = $soort_meel;
        $this->vorm_brood = $vorm_brood;
        $this->gewicht = $gewicht;
    }



    function getGewicht() {
        return $this->gewicht;
    }

    function setGewicht($gewicht) {
        $this->gewicht = $gewicht;
    }

    function getVorm_brood() {
        return $this->vorm_brood;
    }

    function setVorm_brood($vorm_brood) {
        $this->vorm_brood = $vorm_brood;
    }
    
    function getSoort_meel() {
        return $this->soort_meel;
    }

    function setSoort_meel($soort_meel) {
        $this->soort_meel = $soort_meel;
    }

}


$soort_meel = isset($_POST['soortMeel']) && !empty($_POST['soortMeel']) ? $_POST['soortMeel'] : null;
$vorm_brood = isset($_POST['vorm']) && !empty($_POST['vorm']) ? $_POST['vorm'] : null;
$gewicht = isset($_POST['gewicht']) && !empty($_POST['gewicht']) ? $_POST['gewicht'] : null;
$arr_input = isset($_POST['update']) && !empty($_POST['update']) ? $_POST['update'] : null;


// if(isset($_SESSION['update'])) {
//     $arr_input = $_SESSION['update'];
// } else {
//     $brood_winkel['soort_meel'] = $soort_meel;
// }


if(isset($_SESSION['brood_winkel'])) {
    $brood_winkel = $_SESSION['brood_winkel'];
} else {
    $brood_winkel = array(
        new brood("volkorenmeel", "volkorenbrood", "35 gram")
    );
}

// ADD NEW BROOD

if ($soort_meel != null && $vorm_brood != null && $gewicht != null) {
    array_push($brood_winkel, new brood($soort_meel, $vorm_brood, $gewicht));
}

foreach($brood_winkel as $newbrood) {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>" . $newbrood->getSoort_meel() . "</th>";
    echo "<th>" . $newbrood->getVorm_brood() . "</th>";
    echo "<th>" .  $newbrood->getGewicht() . "</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}

$_SESSION['brood_winkel'] = $brood_winkel;
$_SESSION['update'] = $arr_input;


echo $brood_winkel[0];

?>
</body>
</html>
```

`

trying to echo array but doesn't work:

> echo $brood_winkel[0];
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type brood as array
> in index.php on line 148
>
> Error: Cannot use object of type brood as array in
> index.php on line 148

All i want is to set new value in the targetted index of the array.

(if something is not good explained ask them please).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

As the error-message already mentions, you can't print a complete object or array with `echo`. For these cases always use [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

```php
var_dump($brood_winkel[0]);
print_r($brood_winkel[0]);
```

You can use echo, if you want to print out single values. In your case this could be one or multiple attribute values:

```php
echo $brood_winkel[0]->getGewicht();
```

Also, I wanted to add that since all your object-attributes are public you actually don't need your getter-Functions. You can simply access them like this:

```php
echo $brood_winkel[0]->gewicht;
```

This is also the same way how you can update single values of this object:

```php
$brood_winkel[0]->gewicht = 2;
```

Of course you can also replace the complete object at the index of that array:

```php
$test_brood = new brood("meel", "brood", "40");
$brood_winkel[0] = $test_brood;
```

I hope I could help you. Keep it up!